# Error with Zipkin in unit test (cannot mock Span.baggageItems)

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am getting this error when I try to run the unitTest in my spring boot application.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span.baggageItems(Span.java:381)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ZipkinHttpSpanInjector.inject(ZipkinHttpSpanInjector.java:27)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ZipkinHttpSpanInjector.inject(ZipkinHttpSpanInjector.java:15)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.AbstractTraceHttpRequestInterceptor.publishStartEvent(AbstractTraceHttpRequestInterceptor.java:60)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceRestTemplateInterceptor.intercept(TraceRestTemplateInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:86)
```

I notice that I only get this error when I use this version for ***spring-cloud-dependencies***:

```
<spring-cloud.version>Dalston.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
```

but if I use this previous version:

```
<spring-cloud.version>Camden.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
```

everything works as I expect

What can I do in order to avoid this error with the last version?

The unit tests are extended this class in order to mock the SpanAccessor

```
public class AbstractSpanAccessorTest {

@MockBean
private Tracer tracer;

@MockBean
private Span span;

private Random random = new Random();

@Before
public void mockSpan() {
    long id = createId();
    Span spanMock = Span.builder().name("mock").traceId(id).spanId(id).build();
    doReturn(spanMock.traceIdString()).when(span).traceIdString();
    doReturn(span).when(tracer).getCurrentSpan();
    doReturn(span).when(tracer).createSpan(anyString());
}

private long createId() {
    return random.nextLong();
}
```

}

Comment: So it fails only for unit tests? Can you show me your unit test?

Comment: Take a look at AbstractSpanAccessorTest.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you mocking a span? This makes absolutely no sense. Also a Span is never a bean. You already create a normal span via a builder and you should leave that. Assuming that you have set up the Boot context property and  you want to mock out `tracer` bean you should do the following

```
public class AbstractSpanAccessorTest {
@MockBean
private Tracer tracer;

private Random random = new Random();

@Before
public void mockSpan() {
  long id = createId();
  Span spanMock = Span.builder().name("mock").traceId(id).spanId(id).build();
  doReturn(spanMock).when(tracer).getCurrentSpan();
  doReturn(spanMock).when(tracer).createSpan(anyString());
}

private long createId() {
  return random.nextLong();
}
}
```